# Shell-Install one script into group of servers

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

i have a shell script which need to be installed over 100 Ubuntu instances/servers.What is the best way to install the same script on all instance without logging into each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AWS System Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/send-commands-multiple.html) , according to AWS Documentation :

> You can send commands to tens, hundreds, or thousands of instances by
>   using the targets parameter (**the Select Targets by Specifying a
>   Tag** option in the Amazon EC2 console). The targets parameter accepts
>   a Key,Value combination based on Amazon EC2 tags that you specified
>   for your instances. When you execute the command, the system locates
>   and attempts to run the command on all instances that match the
>   specified tags

You can Target Instance by tag :

`aws ssm send-command --document-name name --targets Key=tag:tag_name,Values=tag_value [...]`

or

Targeting Instance IDs:

`aws ssm send-command --document-name name --targets Key=instanceids,Values=ID1,ID2,ID3 [...]`

Read the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/send-commands-multiple.html#send-commands-targeting) for Details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several different options when trying to accomplish this task.

Like [Kush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6077057/kush-vyas) mentioned, AWS System manager is great, but is a tightly coupled AWS service.

[Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html) - You could use Packer to create an AMI of the servers, and have the script installed on them, or just executed whatever the script is doing.

Configuration Management.

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)/[Puppet](https://puppet.com/)/[Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/). - These tools allow you to manage thousands of servers with only a couple of commands. My preference would be for Ansible, it is light weight, the syntax is only yaml, connects over ssh, and still allows use of placing shell scripts, if need be.